# Android studio gradle fails to download dependencies

Tags: react-native, android-studio, gradle

I've created a bare react native project and i started building the project for the first time but it fails  downloading the dependencies,  I tried again with a VPN or changing DNS to bypass internet restrictions but it didn't work , so what is the problem?[image]

Comment: photo is not clear

Answer (score 0):

According to screenshot Gradle tries to download Kotlin plugin from Maven Central Repository. But Kotlin plugin is stored at Gradle Plugins Repository.

To fix that, you will need to add `gradlePluginPortal()` in the `repositories` closure. If project is created with older Android Gradle Plugin version than need to modify `build.gradle` file located in the project's root directory, e.g:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

If project is created with newer Android Gradle Plugin version than need to modify `settings.gradle` file located in the project's root directory, e.g:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, I found out that i have accidentally set proxy on global gradle.properties file in <username>/.gradle and i was also using vpn at the same time, so i remove the proxy and turned on the vpn and it worked.and i also turned off the offline mode.